# Custom resource with Finalizer does not get removed during Helm uninstall

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Helm chart that contains several deployments and a custom resource. The custom resource has a finalizer that is dependent on the deployment to remove. When `helm uninstall` is called, the deployment is removed before the removal of the custom resource completes leaving it orphaned and all of the downstream resources that we supposed to be cleaned up by it's removal.

Is there a way to force the removal of the resource first, maybe through the hook system? Or would it be better to move the custom resource out to it's own chart and then call uninstall in order there?

Comment: Did you try to put the CRD definition in one chart, and then put another resources that use that CRD in another chart, then install and uninstall separately?

Comment: Which version of helm are you using?

Comment: @Bimal Currently v3.0.3, but if there is any newer features it can be upgraded.  Separating the resource into a separate chart is an option, but it makes more sense together as a logical unit. So if there is another option to define that relationship/order of uninstall, that would be preferable.

Comment: Are you using a [subchart](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) for that? If not, have you considered using it?